# How to reset/change owner information of Fujitsu Lifebook T4220

Tags: laptop, bios, tablet

I have bought a used Fujitsu Lifebook T4220 tablet, but the previous owner has set the owner information in the bios, and it can't be changed after setting it, how can i remove, reset or change it?

Comment: I just find out this decoder tool for many laptops as they claim, maybe give it a shot: IBMpass v2.1 Lite — Password decoder & scancode editor for eeprom dumps (Freeware)
http://www.allservice.ro/store/utils/   and let me know if it works!

Comment: BIOS Type is Phoenix TrustedCore v1.12 if it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its necessary that you define a supervisor password. After that you can change the owner information and then set the password back to clear. Then its changed.